# ElasticSearch - How can I update specific field to another index

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Hi I’m currently learning how to use ES for my program.

And I was wondering how i can merge 2 indexes to 1.
For example in case of sqld,

```
Update table 1
set field1 = (select field1 from table 2 where table1.field2 = table2.field2)
```

how can I use this statement at ES dev tools..?

Merging 2 tables(indexes) to 1.

```
index 1
id = A
content1 = “a”
content2 = null

index 2
id = A
content2 = “asdf”

-> after merge

index1
id = A
content1 = “a”
contente2 = “asdf”
```

Answer (score 0):

**Merging 2 tables(indexes) to 1.**

Unlike SQL, It's not easy to combine two indices with a `correlation_id` in elasticsearch.

The best way to do that is to combine the data **before indexing**.

If it's not possible to combine indices before indexing you can use the [enrichment](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-enriching-data.html).

[image]

Comment: Oh… so it is hard to merge 2 indexes… i se…

Comment: Unfortunately, yes :)